# How do i stop my array info from printing twice?

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects

```
var event1Array {
    name: wedding;
    time: ["10:00am", "12:00pm"];
}
var event2Array {
    name: housewarming;
    time: ["7:00pm", "9:00pm"]
}

var eventArray = [event1Array, event2Array];
```

I want to loop through using just two loops (inner and outer) using an alert like this

```
alert("attend a " + eventArray.name + " starting " + theEvent.time)
```

But my event info keeps printing twice like

```
attend a wedding starting 10am, 
attend a wedding starting 12pm
attend a housewarming starting 7pm
attend a housewarming starting 9pm
```

here's the complete code

```
var event1Array 
{ 
    name: wedding; 
    time: ["10:00am", "12:00pm"]; 
}

var event2Array 
{ 
    name: housewarming; 
    time: ["7:00pm", "9:00pm"]; 
} 

var div = document.getElementById("events"); 
var eventArray = [event1Array, event2Array]; 

for (var i = 0; i < eventArray.length; i++) 
{
    var theEvent = eventArray[i];
    for (j = 0; j < theEvent.time.length; j++)
    { 
        console.log("Attending a wedding" + theEvent.name + "starting" + theEvent.time[j]); 
    }
}
```

Comment: how does your loop looks like right now?

Comment: Why do you use two loops if you only want to print the first element in the inner loop?

Comment: post the code for your loop as well.

Comment: What do you actually want the result to be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They aren't Arrays. `event1Array` and `event2Array` are actually `Objects`, so you don't want to loop through them. You should only be looping through the `eventArray`.

```
for (var i = 0,  len = eventArray.length; i < len; i++) {
    alert("attend a " + eventArray[i].name + " starting " + eventArray[i].time[0]);
}
```

Here is a working [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jNVKA/)...

Comment: I know OP didn't say. But suggest:  " ending " + eventArray[i].time[1]

Comment: using eventArray[i].time[0] shows only the first time(i.e 10am for wedding and 7pm for housewarming) but my event info still prints twice

Comment: Here's my code      var event1Array {
    name: wedding;
    time: ["10:00am", "12:00pm"];
}                                               
var event2Array {
    name: housewarming;
    time: ["7:00pm", "9:00pm"]
}

   var div = document.getElementById("events");   
var eventArray = [event1Array, event2Array];
for (var i = 0; i < eventArray.length; i++) {
  var theEvent = eventArray[i];
  for (j = 0; j < theEvent.time.length; j++) {
   console.log("Attending a wedding" + theEvent.name + "starting" + theEvent.time[j]);
  }
    }

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
alert("attend a " + eventArray.name + " starting " + theEvent.time[0])
```

Comment: i just used alert("attend a " + theEvent.name + " starting " + theEvent.time[j]) It printed all the times but in this format  attend a wedding starting 10am, 
attend a wedding starting 12pm
attend a housewarming starting 7pm
attend a housewarming starting 9pm

Comment: @Dabby Seriously, you need to show the code you have. Otherwise it's impossible to give a helpful answer.